# Sonata CSRF token invalid although form correct

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, sonata-admin

While working with Symfony/Sonata, we are facing **CSRF token invalid errors**.

Before, the same code worked perfectly. We assured that the *token is posted correctly* by the form. Strange enough, the error appears only for selected entities.

Browsing all the other Q/A here does not solve the issue.

What else can make CSRF token invalid, if the general communication between client and server works well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
Increase `max_input_vars` in *php.ini*, at least more than the default 1000:

```
max_input_vars=2000
```

**Reason:**
We found out in the nginx logs what caused the CSRF token to fail. Indeed, the token invalidation was just a symptom of a general problem.

The following three error log entries let to the solution:

1. The size of the request of the entity is very big. That is why the first error happend: "It means that the size of the uploaded file was larger than the in-memory buffer reserved for uploads.” (see https://serverfault.com/a/511790). And indeed, Sonata is creating a lot of sub-objects in an entity object.

> *357395 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000742, client: 192.168.10.152,
>   server: xxx request: "POST
>   /admin/entity/1234/edit?uniqid=s588b2b142c3d2 HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxx",
>   referrer: "http://xxx/admin/entity/1234/edit"

2. This was the decisive information. `max_input_vars` defines the, among others, how many input vars will be accepted on a $_POST request. If the (default) limit of 1000 exceeds, PHP will truncate "further input variables [...] from the request". So, **the CSRF token was truncated from the $_POST var by PHP.**

> error_admin: 2017/01/27 12:19:19 [error] 51723#51723: *357395 FastCGI
>   sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables
>   exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.
>   in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 192.168.10.152, server: xxx, request: "POST
>   /admin/entity/1234/edit?uniqid=s588b2b142c3d2 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxx", referrer:
>   "xxx/admin/entity/1234/edit"

3. This is why the third error happened. "Connection reset by peer while sending to client", because the token in the $_POST request obviously was not existent (anymore), because it was either cut off completely or in between. The peer does not find valid token and therefore rejects the request.

> 2017/01/27 12:19:19 [info] 51723#51723: *357395 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client:
>   192.168.10.152, server: xxx, request: "POST /admin/entity/1234/edit?uniqid=s588b2b142c3d2 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxx", referrer:
>   "xxx/admin/entity/1234/edit?uniqid=s588b2b142c3d2"